# Is there a way to position anchors handles length precisely by text input?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, anchor-point

I thought there was a way to edit anchors handles precisely in Illustrator a bit like in Cinema 4D (pictured below) but I can't find it.

[image: Anchor handles (tangents) editor in Cinema 4D]

And when I browse Adobe's help, it seems to be something that I've dreamt of.

In fact I'm just trying to get some symmetry in a circular part of a hand made path. I've drawn a black line on my shape below that highlights the handles length difference between two anchors.

Is the only way of achieving this is by using the ellipse tool ?

[image: how do you get anchors handles of the same length in Adobe Illustrator ?]

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I edited your title, I hope I didn't change your question, if so, feel free to roll it back.

Comment: Possible dupe: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/4237/63979

Comment: Thank you guys, this is the same problem indeed, I guess I didn't found the right wording for my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no numerical input, but you can adjust handles symetrically.

You can make the handles symmetrical when you initially create them, by simply clicking and dragging with the pen tool. Hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> as you click and drag to constrain the angles. Obviously, using some guides will help you make a symmetrical shape.

[image]

To adjust the anchors symmetrically, select the anchor point and hit the <kbd>S</kbd> key, to scale the handles, then click and drag.

[image]

If the anchors are not symmetrical to start with, you can reset the handles to symmetrical ones by clicking the Convert Selected Anchor Points to Corners icon in the toolbar along the top, then convert it back to a Smooth anchor point by clicking the button next to it.

[image]

From there you can simply use the <kbd>S</kbd> key trick again to scale the handles symmetrically.

[image]

Comment: Thank you too for the animated solution, but what I'm looking for is to adjust two different anchors handles to the same length, not just one.

Comment: @Bolos - then I would use guides for that, so that the handles snap to the guides.

Comment: Yep, this works nicely, totally forgot about that! Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

In Illustrator handles are manual. You can have snap to points ON to get a handle dragged to a definite place where already exists an anchor of a curve.

Dragging horizontally and vertically is possible by holding shift key at the same time.

You can allways convert the anchor back to sharp corner and drag from it with the same (=anchor type conversion) tool the handles symmetrically to new direction

An easy way to get LR symmetry is to make a reflected copy (Object > Transform > Reflect > Vertical > Copy) It snaps to its place when smart quides and snap to points are ON.

[image]

You can also make a guide shape:

[image]

Anchor points are dragged to green corners of the orange shape and the handles are dragged to red corners. Send the quide shape to bottom and lock it. You see the snapping easily, the cursor gets to white when you are in the snapping area

Use the layers panel to hide and lock all disturbing shapes

Comment: Thank you for the very nice explanation, not what I was looking for but the guide shape might be the solution.